trying to use Jquery to open and close accordion sections in WP forms
This is the page:https://www.dawleydental.co.uk/online-referral-form-v2/
I have added jquery to open the first section on page on load.
I now want to add next and previous buttins so allow movement between the sections.
For the links I have used
Toggle Next Section and Toggle Previous Section
I want the "toggle next section" links to open the next section and close current and "toggle Previous Setion" to close current and open previous.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
